# order by in Repo.preload

Tags: elixir, ecto

I would like to understand in the queries done by a `Repo.preload`, why there is an `order by` clause.

```
App.Repo.get(Sopitas.Continent, 1) |> App.Repo.preload(:countries)
```

The queries executed are:

```
[debug] QUERY OK source="continents" db=0.4ms
SELECT c0.`id`, c0.`name`, c0.`sm_id`, c0.`inserted_at`, c0.`updated_at`
  FROM `continents` AS c0 WHERE (c0.`id` = ?) [1]
[debug] QUERY OK source="countries" db=3.5ms decode=1.1ms
SELECT c0.`id`, c0.`sm_id`, c0.`name`, c0.`continent_id`, c0.`inserted_at`, c0.`updated_at`, c0.`continent_id`
  FROM `countries` AS c0 WHERE (c0.`continent_id` = ?)
  ORDER BY c0.`continent_id` [1]
```

I want to understand this part is because as far as I understand the `order by` clause add processing time to the execution of the query. I would prefer to avoid the `order by`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not because of `Repo.preload`, that is because this `preload` query returns many records.

`ORDER BY` clause is [added by `Ecto`](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/04dd5bc597147e58375713d86c93fcf91756aa76/lib/ecto/repo/preloader.ex#L174), to effectively group countries (inside the DB engine) before getting a bulk of records.

The link I provided shows a generic `Ecto` approach: as soon as the query is to return many records, it is to sort those by the key.

Comment: Does it really help to the execution time? Maybe when you have a lot of rows it's better for the DB engine, is that true? I am not very familiar with that part of the process when you are retrieving rows with a conditional. So, If I understood correctly, it's better if you first order the rows by the field you are filtering, and then retrieve the rows.

Comment: It heavily depends on the underlying DB engine, but it definitely does not bring any harm. Probably that is why Ecto authors decided to hard-code this `ORDER BY` for everything.

Answer (score 1):

When you are constructing your query fragments you may use SQL clause functions with preload as well. For example:

```
alias App.Repo

Sopitas.Continent
|> Repo.get(1) 
|> Repo.preload([countries: (from c in Country, order_by: c.<your_field_goes_here>)])
```

It's really good to study official [docs](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#order_by/3) ;)